# Customize Drop down list to have categories/sections?

Tags: wordpress, dropdown, contact-form-7, dropdownlistfor

Can something like this be done on CF7? Can it be done with CSS, I've done considerable reasearch and havent found a way to do this..ideally I'd like to do this with an existing form/plugin and not do it all from scratch

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AVUSn.png)

Don't know how to create/customize

Answer (score -1):

I developed a JavaScript plugin, the [HybridDropddown](https://aurovrata.github.io/hybrid-html-dropdown/examples/) field for this kind of listing.

In addition, the [Smart Grid-layout extension for CF7](https://wordpress.org/plugins/cf7-grid-layout/) allows you to builf `dynamic_checkbox` field tags which you can populate with your WordPress categories and format as a HybridDowdown field.  The HybridDrodown uses checkbox inputs, but you can change thier visibilty using CSS as the entire dropdown is can be customised with CSS.

The following CF7 tag,

```
[dynamic_checkbox cat-list limit class:cf7sg-treeview "slug:category:tree"]
```

would use the category terms to populate the dropdown,

[image: HybridDrodpdown list]

The above displays terms with parent (as label), children (as option), grandchildren (as option), by default it uses the first level as labels and the subsequent branch of terms as options with each child branch indented relative to its parent.

If you need to customise this layout, say you want the 1st 2 level of branching to be labels and the 3rd level of branching to be options, then you have 3 ways to achieve this

1. you can use CSS to convert the 2nd level option as a label (remember the HybridDropdown is a pure HTML/CSS construct).  You can disable each 2nd level option to ensure a misplaced click does not actually select it.
2. The Smart Grid-layout allows you to filter a taxonomy query, so you can use a specific branch of a taxonomy as a listing.  See this [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=t9he4Tca5o8&list=PLblJwjs_dFBsynXEstrV3fCIC7GBmK9HW&index=5&t=1258s) on how to filter the query.
3. For more complex custom lists, the Smart Grid-layout plugin's dynamic list fields have a filter option to populate its dropdown, so you can programmatically query your cetegories and select the terms, see this online [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=t9he4Tca5o8&list=PLblJwjs_dFBsynXEstrV3fCIC7GBmK9HW&index=4&t=1198s).

For more information on dynamic checkbox fields see this [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=98DPG5639gE).

Comment: This is fantastic. What do I add to prevent the parent categories from being selected? I just want those parent categories to be labels.

Comment: expanded the answer above to show you want can be achieved.

Comment: I need further clarification. I would like the dynamic checkbox list with parent (as label), children (as option)

Comment: Have you actually tried it on your site?  If your category is made of a single decendent (parent + child) then the UI tag construct will do it automatically for you.

Comment: I appreciate your help and patience. I have it set up on my form. I don't want the parent to be selectable

Comment: https://willowglentutoring.com/test/

Comment: Looks like you got it to work :)

Comment: Yes, I got some outside help and just wanted to share. I did raise another question on your plugin support page: https://wordpress.org/support/topic/dynamic_checkbox-issue-in-message-body/#new-topic-0

Comment: ah yes, and you managed to achieve the dropdown :)